# Date time comparison mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to do a simple date & time comparison in MySQL.Something like this :

`IF( NOW() > Ticket.fixTime )` and the dates are in the following formats

```
IF(2012-09-25 08:47:25  >  2012-09-24 18:15:16)
```

However this returns a wrong result.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What wrong result are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give this way:

```
IF( TO_SECONDS(NOW()) > TO_SECONDS(Ticket.fixTime) )
```

#### Explanation

You can use [`TO_SECONDS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) to convert the time into seconds and compare it.

```
IF('TO_SECONDS(2012-09-25 08:47:25') > TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16'))
```

#### Output

The output is `binary`, i.e., either `1` or `0`:

```
mysql> SELECT TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') > TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') > TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') < TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') < TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### `IF` Condition

The `IF` condition should be used this way:

```
mysql> SELECT IF (TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') < TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16'), 'True', 'False');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IF (TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') < TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16'), 'True', 'False') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| False                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF (TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') > TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16'), 'True', 'False');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IF (TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 08:47:25') > TO_SECONDS('2012-09-24 18:15:16'), 'True', 'False') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| True                                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql IF statement is used as

```
IF(condition, valueA, valueB) // valueA for condition is true otherwise valueB
```

So you should use it like:

```
SELECT IF(NOW() > Ticket.fixTime, 'what you want to show', 'i do not know')
FROM your_table
```

Or you are confused with `IF` and `where`, you just want

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE NOW() > Ticket.fixTime
```